# Older versions of IDA free?

Tags: ida, x86

I'm looking for an IDA free version previous to 7.0 so I can use it in x86 systems, the current one being only x64, but can't seem to find one and it doesn't look like I saved one neither.

Does anyone know where to get one? Or perhaps mind sharing one? (Kind of risky actually, but...)

It's great that even the free version is x64 now, but my RE VMs are mostly x86 so it's quite unconvenient for myself.

Comment: the only previous version of IDA free was 5.0 but it has been taken down from the server (at least the old link doesn't work). One solution for you could be to use alternative tools: [IDA alternatives](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=alternative+to+ida)

Comment: you don't have to (and probably should not) run IDA on the same machine as the malware. Copy the binaries over for analysis and use remote debugging (once you have the full version ;) )

Comment: You are right, but I mostly reverse simple crackmes

Answer (score 5):

If IDA Freeware 5.0 suits your needs, the ScummVM crew [got permission from Hex-Rays](https://www.scummvm.org/news/20180331/) to host a copy in perpetuity to ensure that a version supporting older executable formats will always be available for people wanting to try their hand at adding a new engine to ScummVM.

In addition to that news post I linked, the download link is also on their [HOWTO-Reverse Engineering](https://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php/HOWTO-Reverse_Engineering) wiki page.

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer myself for those who arrive searching for an older x86 version of IDA.
I've found an expired demo for the 6.6 version at https://ida-pro.software.informer.com/6.6/, I don't know if it's safe or not, use with caution.

You know the rest.

Comment: Ok, now **idademo66_windows.exe[6.6.140625 (x86)]** say _Sorry, the evaluation version has expired. _  For correct it change  1 byte  in the file **idaq.exe** offset `0xFC2D` **74->75**. That is replace JE command of CPU to JNE.  (in file search `84 C0 74 1F 68` and replace to `84 C0 75 1F 68`). Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Dr Thorsten Schneider of Erstwhile REA , crackmes.de , put together all the stuff in a zip and hosted it a site named binaryauditing

that site also appears to be taken down by me too virus flagging scanner operators it had a copy of freeida50

someone has unzipped and hosted the site contents in github

[LINK TO COPY OF BINARYAUDITING](https://github.com/Info-security/binary-auditing-training)

this still contains a downloadable copy of idafree50

```
:\>wget -c https://github.com/Info-security/binary-auditing-training/raw/master/idafree50.exe

Length: 16371302 (16M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'idafree50.exe'

idafree50.exe                 100%[=====>]  15.61M   426KB/s    in 70s
```

a preliminary scan passes the muster but you are advised to use caution 
before using the information provided

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not the type of answer you're expecting but if you're looking for something updated, well maintained, free and open-source, why not using [x64dbg](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg) instead IDA?

From what I've read on your comments, I'm pretty much sure this one will cover your needs pretty well.

Here's a list of [features](https://x64dbg.com/#features), as you can see it says "can debug both x64 and x32 applications. There is only one interface."

Answer (score 1):

You can download IDA free 5.0 from here https://samsclass.info/126/proj/idafree50.exe the file from the website of Sam Bowne (@sambowne) he is Professor at City College San Francisco and teaching computer networking and security classes.

Comment: That file matches what I downloaded from the IDA website years ago.  SHA256: 8f83ba2b2173bbc3158300fa9e06ac3dc23165e6db6b67f9f0aba704c719eaf4